# mod_dims package for ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, apache-2.4, httpmodule

I'm porting a client's site to my laptop for development and have run across an Apache module I've never seen before, [mod_dims](https://github.com/beetlebugorg/mod_dims).

Seems like the source has been around for a while, but I haven't found a package for it. Is there a PPA for it maybe? I don't want to build it from source unless I have to. Worst part is the source may only be 2.2 compatible and I have 2.4 on my laptop.

Answer (score 0):

So I just broke down and compiled it from source, and incase you're wondering, it does seem to build against Apache 2.4.

```
# clone mod_dims
git clone git@github.com:beetlebugorg/mod_dims.git

# Install requirements
sudo apt-get install apache2-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev libmagickcore-dev libmagickwand-dev autotools-dev automake 

# Build mod_dims
cd mod_dims
./autorun.sh
./configure
make
sudo make install
```